# Oracle find common value in two different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have a structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE things (
    id,
    personA varchar2,
    personB varchar2,
    attribute ...,
)
```

And I want to find, for a given attribute, if I have at least 1 common person for all my things, how would I go about it?

So if my data is (and it could be more than 2 per attribute):

```
1, John, Steve, Apple
2, Steve, Larry, Apple
3, Paul, Larry, Orange
4, Paul, Larry, Orange
5, Chris, Michael, Tomato
6, Steve, Larry, Tomato
```

For Apple, Steve is my common person, For Orange both Paul and Larry are, and for Tomato I have no common people. I don't need a query that returns all of these at once, however. I have one of these attributes and want 0, 1, or 2 rows depending on what kind of commonality I have. I've been trying to come up with something but can't quite figure out.

Comment: You need a `SELF JOIN`. If you do not want all matches in one query then you can either specify the particular attribute as a part of you `ON` expression or filter it out with WHEN afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

This will give you your `common person` / `attribute` list. I ran it against your sample data and got the expected result. Hope it's at least pointing in the right direction :)

```
WITH NormNames AS (
  SELECT PersonA AS Person, Attribute FROM things
  UNION ALL SELECT PersonB AS Person, Attribute FROM things
)
SELECT
  Person, Attribute, COUNT(*)
  FROM NormNames
  GROUP BY Person, Attribute
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on 11gR2 you could also use [the `unpivot` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#sthref6755) to avoid the self-join:

```
select person, attribute
from (
    select *
    from things
    unpivot (person for which_person in (persona as 'A', personb as 'B'))
)
group by person, attribute
having count(*) > 1;

PERSON     ATTRIBUTE
---------- ----------
Steve      Apple
Paul       Orange
Larry      Orange

3 rows selected.
```

Or to just the the people who match the attribute, which I think is what the end of your question is looking for:

```
select person
from (
    select *
    from things
    unpivot (person for which_person in (persona as 'A', personb as 'B'))
)
where attribute = 'Apple'
group by person, attribute
having count(*) > 1;

PERSON
----------
Steve

1 row selected.
```

---

The `unpivot` translates columns into rows. Run on its own it transforms your original six rows into twelve, replacing the original `persona`/`personb` columns with a single `person` and an additional column indicating which column the new row was formed from, which we don't really care about here:

```
select *
from things
unpivot (person for which_person in (persona as 'A', personb as 'B'));

        ID ATTRIBUTE  W PERSON
---------- ---------- - ----------
         1 Apple      A John
         1 Apple      B Steve
         2 Apple      A Steve
         2 Apple      B Larry
         3 Orange     A Paul
         3 Orange     B Larry
         4 Orange     A Paul
         4 Orange     B Larry
         5 Tomato     A Chris
         5 Tomato     B Michael
         6 Tomato     A Steve
         6 Tomato     B Larry

12 rows selected.
```

The outer query is then doing a simple group.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method.

It implements an unpivot method by cross-joining to a list of numbers (you could use the unpivot method Alex uses) and then joins the result set, hopefully with a hash join for added goodness.

```
with
  row_generator as (
    select 1 counter from dual union all
    select 2 counter from dual),
  data_generator as (
    select
      attribute,
      id       ,
      case counter
        when 1 then persona
        when 2 then personb
      end person
    from
      things,
      row_generator)
select
  t1.attribute,
  t1.person
from
  row_generator t1,
  row_generator t2
where
  t1.attribute = t2.attribute and
  t1.person    =  t2.person   and
  t1.id        != t2.id;
```